# Get random string from array list

Tags: javascript, html

I have the code as below, but can't get it work. It should return 1 value from the myArray, but it returns `"undefined"`. What's the problem?

**HTML**

```
<div id="quote"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March'];
var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

function showquote(){
    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = myArray[rand];
}
showquote();
```

**JSFiddle** can be found **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/9VA2c/).**

Comment: So, rand is already equal to month name.  `document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = rand;`

Comment: First try some basic debugging: `console.log(rand)`

Comment: and although this is simple error... have an upvote for clearly written question with a fiddle too

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback.

Comment: @AndyJones I've submitted a close vote on the basis that the error is so simple and the answers unlikely to help anyone else in future.

Comment: I voted to close too, although I do appreciate the clarity of the question. It is well formatted with a clear example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `rand`' is already the value from the array (e.g. "January"),
`var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];`

so you cannot get value from the array again using `myArray['January']`.

You should change your Js function as below

```
function showquote(){
    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = rand;
}
```

Or change your variable

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
```

Comment: @DNac this is the clearest answer here, the only one to correctly explain the double indexing into the array.  IMHO you should accept this one.

Answer (score 4):

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/9VA2c/1/) fiddle works.

```
var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March'];
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);

function showquote(){
    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = myArray[rand];
}
showquote();
```

the problem is with this line

```
var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)]; // dereferenced myArray[] twice here
```

Comment: @ejay_francisco the error is _not_ a syntax error.  It's merely a case of the OP accidentally trying to dereference `myArray[]` twice - once in the `rand` call and again in `showquote()`.

Answer (score 2):

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March'];

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);

function showquote(){

    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = myArray[rand];
}
showquote();
```